# Swift: UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I share an invite through UIActivityViewController by passing the text. I am able to achieve it. But I have display issue as shown in the image below.  A greyed box displayed over the text at the top. Below is my code

```
    let objectToShare = inviteReferrals.inviteData
    let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [objectToShare], applicationActivities: [])
    present(vc, animated: true)
```

Can any one help me, why this box comes and how to avoid it.
[ActivityViewControllerDisplay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/351g4.png)

Comment: Do you add any views directly to your Window ? If not, try testing on another device and check if this issue persists.

Comment: Use View Hierarchy Debugger tool in XCode to see what the gray box is

Answer (score 0):

```
let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [objectToShare], applicationActivities: nil)
activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view
self.present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```